# Select the item with least difference among its fields

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of items.
I have to select item with minimum difference between two of its properties.

Eg : Student { string Name, int ScoredMarks, int TotalMarks }
Note : Total marks will not be the same for all students.
I have to select the student with least difference of TotalMarks and ScoredMarks.
I was able to do this way

```
int minDiff = students.Min(x => (x.TotalMarks - x.ScoredMarks));
var result = from s in students
             where s.TotalMarks - s.ScoredMarks == minDiff
             select s;
```

Can i achieve it in a single statement? What would be the perfomance of doing this way?
which would be optimistic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Math.Abs` to get the absolute difference, order by it and take the first.

```
Student minDiff = students
        .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.TotalMarks - x.ScoredMarks))
        .FirstOrDefault();
if(minDiff != null)
{
     // ...
}
```

If you want the best performance you should use `MinBy` of Skeets [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs). My approach needs to order **all** items by the value before it takes the one with the lowest difference.

> If I have to select all students with minimum differnce i.e what if i have more than one student with same minimum difference.

Then you could use `GroupBy`:

```
var minDiffGroup = students
            .GroupBy(x => Math.Abs(x.TotalMarks - x.ScoredMarks))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .FirstOrDefault();
foreach(Student student in minDiffGroup)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but I would use 'FirstOrDefault()'.

Comment: If I  have to select all students with minimum differnce i.e what if i have more than one student with same minimum difference.

Comment: Sorry, this is will change the behaviour. The original approach does not use Abs, you've added Abs() here. The question implies that Abs should be used, but his sample code does not so your code here will return different results.

Comment: @VVutpala: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @CarstenSchütte: Maybe his code worked because TotalMarks is always greater than ScoredMarks. So my answer also works. Apart from that _"I have to select the student with least difference of TotalMarks and ScoredMarks."_ sounds like he might need `Math.Abs` (but it doesn't hurt anyway).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Great answer. Thanks a lot Tim

Comment: @Tim: You're right, I just wanted make clear that Math.Abs() was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Student TheOne = StudentList.OrderBy<Student, int>(x => x.TotalMarks - x.ScoredMarks).First<Student>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just combine the two.

```
var result = from s in students
             where s.TotalMarks - s.ScoredMarks == students.Min(x => (x.TotalMarks - x.ScoredMarks))
             select s;
```

One note though, it depends on what you're querying against which decides it this is a 'better' solution performance-wise. If it is linq-to-objects, than the student.Min(...) is run every time, which is a worse performance. If it is Entity Framework, than the whole lambda is translated to SQL, which is a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

[MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has MinBy and MaxBy functions:

And to further simplify this, I suggest adding a property to your Students object

```
public int PriorTotalMarks { get { return this.TotalMarks - this.ScoredMarks; } }
```

The additional property can be bound to a datagrid, aggregated, etc.. without the extra complication of subtraction mixed in.

Then, using Jon Skeet's MinBy, you would simply write:

```
Students.MinBy(s => s.PriorTotalMarks);
```